# How to move values to another column based on conditions of other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

In my data set some of the data has been inputted into the wrong column. Specifically, some values for 'power' have ended up in the 'r' column and the only way to identify them is that 'theta', 'z' and 'power' are all NaN but 'r' has a numeric value. How do I identify these rows and then move these values from 'r' to 'power' in python? The rows in question look similar to these:

Problematic rows:

[image: Problem rows example]

Comment: Can anyone help? Is anymore information needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the following:

```
m = ((df.theta.notnull()) | (df.z.notnull()) | (df.power.notnull()))
df.power.where(m, df.r, inplace=True)
df.r.where(m, None, inplace=True)
```

Like this you first create a series `m`, identifying all those lines where theta, z and power are not all null/NaN. Then, where m is False, you set the column power to r and the column r to None. By inplace=True you tell it, that it should be immediately applied to the original data frame.

I hope this helps you. Please let me know if there are some problems with it still.

Edit:
Following is a small example of how I imagine this behaviour should look like. It creates a dataframe with four columns one, two, three and four and if two and three are both empty, I move the value from one to four. one will then be None:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, np.NaN, np.NaN], [3, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN], [5, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN], [7, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN]], columns=["one", "two", "three", "four"])
m = (df.three.notnull()) | (df.two.notnull())

print(df)
df.four.where(m, df.one, inplace=True)
df.one.where(m, None, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Christian, this has worked in putting the values in 'power' however they are still also in the 'r' column. How would i now drop these values from 'r'?

Comment: No problem. I added the extra line `df.r.where(m, None, inplace=True)` to my answer, which should do the trick for you.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work as the condition of m is no longer met after the values are added to power. A dirty way around this is to make a new condition `n = ((df_del.theta.notnull()) | (df_del.z.notnull()))` and then use your line. This led to 7 more r's being removed than were added to power which is not a huge problem but if you have a better solution that would be great

Comment: Hm. To clarify something: Did you reexecute `m = ((df.theta.notnull()) | (df.z.notnull()) | (df.power.notnull()))` after `df.power.where(m, df.r, inplace=True)`? Because I would be a bit surprised if the `df.r.where` then would operate on different lines as `df.power.where`.

Comment: I added a small example of my understanding of the problem to my answer. Can you confirm, that this is as you see it? Maybe I have a mixup there still.

Comment: Very peculiar, it wasnt working but then I executed from the top again and now it is working, no idea why. Thank you anyway for the help and apologies for the waste of time at the end!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. If you don't mind you could mark my answer as accepted.